# Move navbar to right using CSS

Tags: html, css

[This is what I've done so far](http://jsfiddle.net/3eh11owg/). The problem that I faced, was my `<li>` stacked in the left corner. How to make them inline in the right corner?

HTML

```
<div id="page">
    <div class="header Fixed"> <a href="#menu"></a>Demo
        <ul id="account">
            <li><a href="#">Username</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Logout</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="content">
        <div id="first">
            <p><strong>This is the first section.</strong>

                <br />Notice how the fixed header and footer slide out along with the page.</p>
            <p><a href="#menu">Open the menu.</a>

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer Fixed">Copyright @ 2015 , All rights reserved.</div>
    <nav id="menu" th:include="${filename}"></nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
     background-color: #fff;
     font-family:'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
     font-size: 14px;
     line-height: 22px;
     color: #666;
     position: relative;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
body * {
     text-shadow: none;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
     line-height: 1;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
}
h4, h5, h6 {
     font-size: 16px;
}
p {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
a, a:link, a:active, a:visited, a:hover {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
nav:not(.mm-menu) {
     display: none;
}
.header, .content, .footer {
     text-align: center;
}
.header, .footer {
     background: #0ca3d2;
     color: #fff;
     line-height: 40px;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 50px;
}
.header.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.footer.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.header a {
    background: center center no-repeat transparent;
    background-image: url(data:image/png;
base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABkAAAAZCAYAAADE6YVjAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAADhJREFUeNpi/P//PwOtARMDHQBdLGFBYtMq3BiHT3DRPU4YR4NrNAmPJuHRJDyahEeT8Ii3BCDAAF0WBj5Er5idAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
}
.footer a {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
}
.content {
    padding: 150px 50px 50px 50px;
}
#account li {
    list-style-type: none;
    top: 0;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    float: right;
}
#account li a {
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#account li a:hover {
    color: #f0ad4e;
}
#intro, #first {
    height: 400px;
}
#intro {
    padding-top: 0;
}
#first {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-top: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> position: absolute   ---The element is positioned relative to its first
>   positioned (not static) ancestor element

The thing is that you have this style:

```
.header a{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
}
```

So all your `<a>` are being positioned to that `top` and `left` because you don't have any positioned (not static) ancestor element.

Set `position: relative` to `ul#account li` and it works.

Here a minimal example of what you want to achieve(comment img link)

```css
.header {
    background: #0ca3d2;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 40px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 50px;
}

.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#account{
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
}

#account li{
    float: left;   
    list-style: none;    
}

#account li a{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#account li a:hover{
    background: #216A9D;
}
```

```html
<div class="header fixed"> <a href="#menu"></a>Brand Name
    <ul id="account">
        <li><a href="#">Username</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works but the li under `#account` is going down. not inline in the blue box. How to do it?

Comment: That is because you have `.header{ height: 40px}` so you `ul` is out of it, anyway can you link a photo of what you want to achieve, I would have a better idea and I can help you.

Comment: Check this one, I want the user account and logout in the right corner, then the brand name in left corner. [link](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ht5VoQh0TZU/VMpQrN9isuI/AAAAAAAAAeM/VURVSjP7UaM/s1600/bootstrap-custom-navbar.png). Thanks.

Comment: Great. Thanks ya. It's what I want.

Comment: Hi, @Yandy_Viera can you add the hamburger icon in the left of Brand Name? when I add that, it's automatically add to left in the Username and Logout, not in the left Brand Name. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which is the hamburger icon you're talking about, I can't see it in the jsfiddel neither in the img of your comment link.

Comment: in this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3eh11owg/6/) I've update with your answer, and the hamburger icon is under the blue header. If you, change the position of background, the blue header will disappear and changed with hamburger icon. The `background-image` with `background`.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Yandy_Viera, I can resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using float:right; It will be easier if the code is shown...

Comment: I'd already add the code in this post, and also the `float:right` in my css, but it's still can't move.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than:

```
.header a
```

use

```
.header > a
```

and few more style changes:

```
#account {
    float: right;
}
#account li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    display: inline;
}
```

You did some mistakes in your code. Check the float property you write. Study: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Also, You used position:absolute for .header a, This will apply to all anchors present under header. This was the main issue.

Hope it helps you.